# Remove unwanted parameter

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm trying to get rid of parameter "?status=OK" fom the url below.

**Current:**

https://example.com/download/d2e9cc4f-f7df-4ebd-a0e4-7836c8013075?status=OK

**Goal:**

https://example.com/download/d2e9cc4f-f7df-4ebd-a0e4-7836c8013075

**Nginx:**

```
location /download/ {
    rewrite ^(/download/.*)?$ $1 permanent;
}
```

Unfortunately the above doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query string is not part of the normalized URI used by `location` and `rewrite` statements to test the regular expression.

You can check for the presence of any argument with `if ($args) { ... }` or only check for the presence of the `status=` argument with `if ($arg_status) { ... }`.

For example:

```
location /download/ {
    if ($args) { return 301 $uri; }

    ...          # do something with the corrected URI
}
```

The `rewrite` statement is also capable of removing the query string with `rewrite ^(.*)$ $1? permanent`, but the `return` statement seems simpler. See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.